# VSTS/TFS Extension Development - URL Limit for GET Request for getWorkItems() Method

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

We are developing a VSTS/TFS Extension. We are also querying Work Items data using Rest Client provided by VSTS/TFS. We are using below method to Get Details of all the work items - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1?view=vsts#method_getWorkItems

The method getWorkItems generates a GET request. All the Work Item IDs are passed as query parameters which exceed the URL Limit of 2048 characters. Thus to tackle that, for now, we are splicing the work items Ids in smaller chunks. But then it increases the Rest API calls.

Is there any other method through which I can Get details of all work Items using any method in VSTS/TFS defined list?

Comment: If you can, define a work item query that matches your expected results, then you can simply request that query.

Comment: @jessehouwing - getWorkItems method takes Ids[] as input and not wiql (work item query language)

Comment: So... Query by WIQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: @jessehouwing - Query by WIQL only returns the IDs of Work Items and not the field values. To retrieve field values for each work item we have to use the getWorkItems method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/336135/vststfs-extension-development-url-limit-for-get-re.html)

```
let client = VssService.getCollectionClient(WitClient.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient5);
client.getWorkItemsBatch(<WitContracts.WorkItemBatchGetRequest>{ ids: [1, 2, 3] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `queryById()` or `queryByWiql()` function in [TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1?view=vsts) to retrieve work items through Query.

For example:

```
 witClient.queryById('7633dab2-89e4-4da9-b03d-a16728ab71c5', projectId)
                    .then(function (workitemResult) {....})



query = {
                        query: "SELECT [System.Id] "
                             + "FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' "
                             + "AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Closed','Completed','Removed','Done') "
                             + "AND [System.TeamProject] = @project"
                    };
witClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId, allteams[0].id).then(function (result) {


                        console.log(result);

                    });
```

Comment: With queryById, the query must be saved in VSTS or TFS. We are not saving the queries there, instead, we are using the second method queryByWiql. But Query by WIQL only returns the IDs of Work Items and not the field values. To retrieve field values for each work item we have to use getWorkItems method.

Comment: You can tell it which field by passing in the field names in the select clause. Your current query just requests system.id

Comment: @jessehouwing - Query by WIQL returns only Work Item Ids. If you pass the field names in the select clause, it returns the reference names of those fields & not the field values for each Work Items. Check Wiql response [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=vsts-rest-4.1#response)